# How to connect to a DB with given credentials in VisualStudio

Tags: database, connection, credentials

I have the DB and the relative credentials.
But I can't figure out how to connect to the DB, maybe I need to create a new Login for that DB?

The connection string in my web.config file is:

> add name="ConnectionString1" connectionString="Password=xxxxx;Persist
>   Security Info=True;User ID=yyyyy;Initial Catalog=zzzzz;Data
>   Source=.\SQLEXPRESS" />

I tried many ways but I simply don't find a way to create the connection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Usually checking MSDN is the best place to check for these things. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171886.aspx
This might be the specific steps you're looking for - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk9yw1t.aspx

Comment: ok but the question is quite precise, MSDN is like a bible very verbose and not explicit...

Comment: what I have are the user and the password, but i don't understand if those are already "understood" by the DB or I have somehow to specify to DB that with that credentials one can access...